# Best way to define set of constexpr values for non-mutating algorithms

Tags: c++, templates, boost, constexpr

I would like to use non-mutating algorithms from `<algorithm>` and boost range algorithms on set of values known at compile time. I want to know which approach would be most effective(in terms of performance and memory), excluding switch-case approach.

Let's consider enum(class or not) with some values.

```
enum Enum
{
   One,
   Two,
   Three
};
```

Let's consider trivial function `bool isOneOrTwo(Enum e)`.
Using `<algorithm>` approach I know it can be written in two ways:
1. `std::initializer_list<T>`

```
bool isOneOrTwo(Enum e)
{
    constexpr std::initializer<Enum> oneAndTwo{One, Two};
    return std::any_of(std::begin(oneAndTwo),
                       std::end(oneAndTwo),
                       [e](auto i){return e == i;});
}
```

2. `std::array<T,N>`

We got `make_pair` and `make_tuple` but unfortunately we don't have `make_array<T>(T&&..)` function so I wrote one:

```
template<typename... T>
constexpr auto make_array(T&&... args)
{
    return std::array<typename std::common_type<T...>::type, sizeof...(T)>{{std::forward<T>(args)...}};
}
```

Then function can be made in this way:

```
bool isOneOrTwo(Enum e)
{
    constexpr auto oneAndTwo = make_array(One, Two);
    return std::any_of(std::begin(oneAndTwo),
                       std::end(oneAndTwo),
                       [e](auto i){return e == i;});
}
```

Which one is better(`std::initializer_list<T>` or `std::array<T,N>`) or there is other way do it faster/cheaper?

And would it have any impact if I change `std::any_of(begin_it, end_it, lambda)` to `boost::algorithm::any_of_equal(make_iterator_range(begin_it, end_it), value)`?

Comment: I think you might have reduced the problem a bit too much. Could you try to describe the *real* problem you try to solve, otherwise `e != Three` would be my solution.

Comment: If you will be testing for ranges of consecutive values often, you might also want to provide a way to produce code similar to what you would get from `(e >= min && e <= max)`, rather than always using only `==` comparisons.

Comment: `enum` is only a simple example, it can be set of `constexpr` `struct` with only `operator==()`, nonconsecutive enum, etc.

Comment: Did you try #1? A `std::initializer_list` that is not empty can never be `constexpr`.

Comment: In C++17 you can write `constexpr auto oneAndTwo = std::array{One, Two};` to use class template deduction instead of needing `make_array`.

Comment: @aschepler gcc 6.3 on ideone says otherwise https://ideone.com/PA9G8J

Comment: @MamCieNaHita Hmm. gcc 8.1 and clang head reject it: https://godbolt.org/g/12ma8r